# R tidyverse enable use of multiple CPU cores

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a core i9 in my work computer and I was wondering is it possible to enable use of multiple CPU cores to produce `ggplots` more quickly? Or is `ggplot` more `GPU` dependent?

Data (`df`):

The can be accessed [here](https://app.box.com/s/e2gjyg1el5og9f9tudb5i60pk6xmuly6). I wasn't able to paste it since the data is big. And I guess this dataset is necessary for the question since I want to speed up `ggplot`.

Sample code:

```
df = read.csv("path/TMean.csv")

    gg = df %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = year, y = tmean)) +
      geom_point(aes(color = "Temperature"), size = 2, shape = 1, alpha = 0.1) +
      geom_smooth(method = lm, aes(linetype = "LM"), se = FALSE, color = "red") +
      scale_linetype_manual(values = 2, name = NULL) +
      scale_colour_manual(values = "deepskyblue4", name = "Legend") +
      theme(text = element_text(size = 16)) +
      xlab("Year") +
      ylab("Mean Temperature (\u00B0C)") +
      ggtitle("1980-2021 Historical Change")+
      guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 0.5), order = 1))
    
    # Model and label formula and R^2
    
    lm(tmean ~ year, data = df) -> model_df
    get_formula(model_df)
    
    scales::percent(summary(df)$r.squared, accuracy = 0.01) -> r_square
    summary(r_square)$r.squared -> r_squared_df
    r_squared_df = round(r_squared_df, digits = 4)
    
    #Now we need to add the text to the plot:
    gg + 
      geom_text(x = 1983.2, y = 30.8,
                label = paste0("Formula = ", get_formula(model_df)),
                color = 'red') +
      geom_text(x = 1980, y = 30.4,
                label = paste0("R\U00B2 = ", r_squared_df),
                color = 'blue')
```

Comment: Are you producing more than one plot? You might be able to run jobs in parallel, but the ggplot code it not written with native support for multithreading so you can't really make any 1 plot faster. Any tips for speeding up plotting would really depend on exactly what your data look like and what type of plot you are trying to make.

Comment: ggplot2 doesn't have any kind of multithreading. give an example of what you want to do though and we might be able to help.

Comment: @MrFlick alright I'll post some code, do we need the original data too, but it is a big dataset?

Comment: An example would be useful. I find that `ggplot` can get bogged down with more than perhaps 10-50k plotted elements, so when I'm working on larger data I usually try to summarize, sample, or rely on related tools like `rasterly`: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rasterly/vignettes/introduction.html